Перенос слова «деревьев»
Господа филологи, помогите понять, является ли перенос деревь-ев верным?
Как доказать/аргументировать правильность такого переноса? Речь о неотделимости твердого и мягкого знака, сонорных, или ещё о чем- то?
Чем руководствоваться при совершении такого переноса?

• Начнем с морфемного разбора:
дерево — -дерев- (корень), -о (окончание). Перенос по слогам — де-ре-во;
деревьев — де-ревь-ев (перенос строго по слогам; предпочтительный).
Перенос де-ре-вьев разбивает слог. Но современные правила это разрешают, поэтому так тоже можно переносить.
• Из правил  переноса:

...многие слова можно переносить различными способами; при этом следует предпочитать такие переносы, при которых не разбиваются значащие части слова.


Спасибо! Да, со слогами понятно, а вот именно по переносу тут, выходит, применяется правило связки с мягким знаком... Короче говоря, так я и не понимаю до конца аргументацию переноса...

Правила переноса на портале Грамота.ру

Запрещено: бол-ьшой, бул-ьон, то  есть отрыв и перенос Ь, обозначающего мягкость согласного. Иначе мы прочтем согласный как твердый. Вот в чем принципиальное решение.

Нельзя: ДЕРЕВ-ЬЕВ, все остальное можно!

Разрешено: кресть-янин, крестья-нин, кре-стьянин, крес-тьянин.

Тогда правильно: де-ревьев, дере-вьев, деревь-ев.

А перенос по слогам —  это тоже вопрос, так как сама разбивка проблематична, есть варианты и даже разные принципы.

По составу слова (с учетом морфемной структуры) тоже нет жестких правил, в том числе относительно корня и приставки  (см. корректирующие правила в конце темы).


Для справок (о делении на слоги)
 Слог определяется как произносительный квант речи. 
 Он не выражает смысловых связей звуков, как 
 морфемы,  а  характеризуется АКУСТИЧЕСКОЙ ИЛИ 
 АРТИКУЛЯЦИОННОЙ слитностью звуков при их 
 произношении. 
 По одной теории, слог – это один гласный звук или 
 несколько звуков, которые произносятся ОДНИМ 
 ТОЛЧКОМ выдыхаемого воздуха (лод-ка). По другой 
 теории, слоги строятся по принципу ВОСХОДЯЩЕЙ 
 ЗВУЧНОСТИ (ло-дка). 


В полном академическом справочнике читаем:
Не разрешается отделять от предшествующей согласной буквы ъ и ь. Правильные переносы:
отъ-езд, коль-цо, перь-ями, буль-он; не допускаются переносы: от-ъезд, кол-ьцо, пер-ьями, бул-ьон.
Таким образом правильно: деревь -ев, де- ревьев.
Правила переноса

Спасибо большое за ответ! А то я тут прямо в горячем споре с учителем, который уверен, что деревь- ев писать нельзя.

@Елена Как видите, учитель прав.
